# Custom display format for a pandas DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to *display* a `DataFrame` using a custom format for the index.

I know how to convert a `DatetimeIndex` into string using some format, and I am also aware of the nice [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) introduced in 0.17.1.  However, the styling mechanism doesn't seem to provide a way to custom format the index itself (or did I miss something?).

Here is a simple example

```
In[10]:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2017-01-01', freq='D', periods=3),
    columns=['v'],
    data=np.arange(3)
)
df

Out[10]:
            v
2017-01-01  0
2017-01-02  1
2017-01-03  2

In[11]:
df.index.format(formatter=lambda t: f'{t:%Y-%m-%d %a}')

Out[11]:
['2017-01-01 Sun', '2017-01-02 Mon', '2017-01-03 Tue']
```

I would like to be able to display `df` as:

```
Out[10]:
                v
2017-01-01 Sun  0
2017-01-02 Mon  1
2017-01-03 Tue  2
```

One inelegant way is of course to do:

```
def dow_display(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df.index = df.index.format(formatter=lambda t: f'{t:%Y-%m-%d %a}')
    return df
```

and when desired, convert the `df` for purpose of displaying, but I find that pretty awful.  It would be so much nicer to use the styling capability.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to simply add a new column:

```
In [11]: df.index.weekday_name
Out[11]: Index(['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday'], dtype='object')

In [12]: df.index.weekday_name.str[:3]
Out[12]: Index(['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue'], dtype='object')

In [13]: df["weekday"] = df.index.weekday_name.str[:3]

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
            v weekday
2017-01-01  0     Sun
2017-01-02  1     Mon
2017-01-03  2     Tue
```

Comment: I don't think there is a custom format display option (like there is for floats)

Comment: well, sure (and even simpler is `s['dow'] = s.index.strftime('%a')`), but then any shift operation will confuse the heck out of anyone looking at the result...

Answer (score 0):

I can only using string make up the format...

```
df.index=df.index.astype(str)+' '+df.index.weekday_name.str[:3]
df
Out[1108]: 
                v
2017-01-01 Sun  0
2017-01-02 Mon  1
2017-01-03 Tue  2
```

Comment: the issue is that modifies the DataFrame. I want to avoid that and have a display-only method. Also, depending on the format, the modified index could be non-monotonic, which may cause trouble for other operations.